# Building a stick fighting game, Silverlight or Flash?

Tags: flash, silverlight

what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: One is Adobe the other is Microsoft. So, those would both be cons ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a fantastic comparison of the two featured in Smashing Magazine:

[Flash vs. Silverlight: What Suits Your Needs Best?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/09/flash-vs-silverlight-what-suits-your-needs-best/)

Comment: the best part of the article has to be the flame wars in the comments. As an aside, Silverlight 4 addresses a few of the issues mentioned in the article.

Comment: that was a great article, even though the silverlight version compared seems old.

Comment: Well a "good" comparison. I don't know too much about Silverlight but I do know a fair bit about Flash and its clear the author article has only had a quick play around especially when it comes to the animation segment. Also to get around the scripting in Flash one can always program in HaXe and get goodies like generics and then compile to SWF and get better performance than the Adobe compiler :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Chrome Experiments](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/).  Why use proprietary plug-ins when you can use standards?  The knowledge and skills you develop will be useful and very marketable in a year's time.

Comment: I'm amazed with that dude... I never thought this is possible in pure html & javascript...
thanks alot for sharing :) but how those applications were built is it using GWT?

Comment: No, All you need is the Notepad!  Of course there are some IDE's and more will arrive sooner or later.  HTML5, Canvas, and SVG will possibly eliminate most of proprietary plug-ins.

Comment: What standards? HTML5 isn't a standard.

Answer (score 1):

**Flash:**

Pros
- probably installed on 90% (or more) of the world's computers by now.

Cons
- a fair amount of bad press due to bad Flash ads. There are several Flash blocking plugins for Firefox (for example).

**Silverlight:**

Pros
- it's being actively developed by Microsoft so any limitations are being addressed.
- developing in Silverlight is quite like developing a desktop application (in my opinion)
- the same code can be run both as a browser application and desktop application (recompile required).

Cons
- relatively new technology so it's not got as wide a user base.
- it's developed by Microsoft ;)
- relatively little used outside Microsoft and, despite Mono/Moonlight, runs only on Windows platforms. (thanks Rob)

Comment: Silverlight con: compared to Flash, relatively little used outside Microsoft and, despite Mono/Moonlight, runs only on Windows platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: Silverlight is free to develop for. VS Express, compared to VS full, is, well, almost indistinguishable. If you haven't been using it for years you won't need anything in the full edition.

Flex however costs lots of money. Lots. And i'm guessing by virtue of you asking the question that you don't have a copy.